# ignored children tests in Frisby JS with jasmine-node

Tags: javascript, meteor, jasmine, jasmine-node, frisby.js

I use Frisy with jasmine-node to test an Meteor API.

I want to test the remove of a discussion in a chat App. For this, I need to create a new discussion in chat and add a message in the discussion.

I noticed that my test fail if I put it after the second .then() method. It fails also after the third .then(). However, it works correctly after the first .then() method.

An example code with explicit failed test **expect(false).toBe(true);**:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
describe("chat update", function() {
  it("message added", function(done) {
    frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat', {
      name: "remove"
    })
    .then(function (res) {
      let id = res._body.id;
      expect(false).toBe(true); // (1) it fails the test
      frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat/'+id+'/addmessage', 
        {
          auteur: "Samuel",
          message: "My message"
        }
      )
      .then(function (res) {
        expect(false).toBe(true); // (2) Without (1) it's ignored by frisby
        frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat/remove', 
          {id: id}
        )
        .then(function (res) {
          expect(false).toBe(true); // (3) Without (1) it's ignored by frisby
        })
      });
    })
    .done(done);
  })
});
```

If I run the test, it will fail thanks to **expect(false).toBe(true); // (1) it fails the test** line.
If I remove this line, the test will run and jasmine valid it as right.

Do you know a way to don't ignore the (2) and (3) tests ?

Comment: Are you using the old version of the Frisby or the newer version? I ask, because the "old" version used jasmine-node and the new one uses Jest.

Comment: I use the newer. I found the solution and I put it as an answer. I forgot the return operators. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, I found the solution.
It's because I forgot to **return all frisby action** (except the first one) like in the following code:

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
describe("chat update", function() {
  it("message added", function(done) {
    frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat', {
      name: "remove"
    })
    .then(function (res) {
      let id = res._body.id;
      return frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat/'+id+'/addmessage', 
        {
          auteur: "Samuel",
          message: "My message"
        }
      )
      .then(function (res) {
        return frisby.post('http://localhost:3000/api/chat/remove', 
          {id: id}
        )
        .then(function (res) {
          expect(false).toBe(true); // Will fail the test
        })
      });
    })
    .done(done);
  })
});
```

You may notice the **return** operators before **frisby.post()**.
I hope it will help !